# sed to format extracted text in file

Tags: sed

I am using `sed` to extract from a large file.  The below seems to extract the data in the below format and from there I am not sure how to clean the file up to look the desired output. There probably is a better way I am just not sure how.  Thank you :).

1. any leading symbol (, or : or ;) is removed if it preceeds text in `$2`
2. all commas in `$3` are conveted to `;`
3. `$3` has the white space in front the text removed
4. there are 3 tab-delimeted fields in output

**file** space-delimited

```
81201 APC   gene analysis; full gene sequence
81210 BRAF  , gene analysis, full gene sequence, V600 variant
```

**desired output** tab-delimited

```
81201   APC gene analysis;full gene sequence
81210   BRAF    gene analysis;full gene sequence;V600 variant
```

**sed**

```
sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g' file.txt | sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' > file
```

**original file**

```
81201 APC (adenomatous polyposis coli) (eg, familial adenomatosis 
polyposis [FAP], attenuated FAP) gene
analysis; full gene sequence
81210 BRAF (B-Raf proto-oncogene, serine/threonine kinase) (eg, colon 
cancer), gene analysis, V600 variant(s)
```

Comment: What are `$2` and `$3` in your description? What is `'s/([^()]*)//g'` supposed to do, in your own words?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to escape some of those parentheses?

Comment: `$2` is `APC` and `BRAF`.... `$3` is `gene analysis; full gene sequence` in line 1 and `, gene analysis, full gene sequence, V600 variant` in line 3.... in creating that `file` i use `sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'` to remove the parenthesis and then pipe it to a `sed` that combines every 2 lines.  I will add the original file to the post.   Thank you :).

Comment: That might better a better approach :).

Comment: Ah, so that has nothing to do with your question at all? Why post it here? You should post what you did to attempt to solve the remaining problem instead.

Comment: You need to swap those commands if I am not mistaken. First remove the newlines, then remove the cruft.

Comment: After removing the `(....)` from the original file and joining every two lines.... I tried to remove the whitespace with `sed`, I also tried adding tabs with `awk` but that did not work as expected.  I also tried `awk '{ gsub(/.*,/,"",$3) } 1'` to remove the commas and whitespace. Thank you.

Comment: Also, your first group has three lines in it, which throws the whole thing off...

Comment: I am unable to get `'s/([^()]*)//g'` to work as you claim. What version of sed are you using?

Comment: So I found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196149/79307. Now the problem is that after cleaning up parens, there is only one line in the second group... How do you fix that?

Comment: I am using `sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`.  Thank you again :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that the commands shown work as expected, but since that is not part of your question, I will ignore it.

Here's a way to do the final cleanup with a couple of relatively simple expressions:

```
sed -e 's/^\s*\([^ \t]\+\)\s\+\([^ \t]\+\)\s\+[,;]\?\s*\(.*\)/\1\t\2\t\3/' \
    -e 's/[,;]\s*/;/g'
```

The first expression only captures the parts that you want: no extra spaces or commas. The bolded sections represent the capture groups that are retained. The second part replaces *all* commas with semicolons, since there should not be any commas outside the third field by the time the expression is applied. Keep in mind that `sed` always uses greedy quantifiers so the whitespace problem is correctly handled by `\s\+`.

Depending on your version of `sed`, you may need to play with the escaping a bit. You may also need to replace `\s` with `[ \t]`.

**Input**

```
81201 APC   gene analysis; full gene sequence
81210 BRAF  , gene analysis, full gene sequence, V600 variant
```

**Output**

```
81201   APC     gene analysis;full gene sequence
81210   BRAF    gene analysis;full gene sequence;V600 variant
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and explanation :)